# Cross-Browser with ASP.NET Multiline TextBox Issue

Tags: asp.net, textbox, cross-browser

On an event, my textbox fields are populated from an SQL Database. Nothing fancy with the textbox, just an ID, TextMode, and some CSS.

Here's the background code:

```
Protected Sub LocationControl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LocationControl.SelectedIndexChanged
    If LocationControl.SelectedValue = "(New Location)" Then
        Clear()
    Else
        Dim filter As String = "locationID = '" + LocationControl.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'"
        Dim dv As DataView = CType(SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
        dv.RowFilter = filter
        For Each drv As DataRowView In dv
            LocName.Text = drv("locationName").ToString()
            LocAddress.Text = drv("locationAddress").ToString()
            LocDirections.Text = drv("drivingdirections").ToString()
            LocURL.Text = drv("URL").ToString()
            statusDDL.SelectedValue = drv("statusID").ToString()
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

The code works, but when I run the it under any browse but IE any extra line is created above all the multiline textboxs.

Any ideas?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. You're iterating several rows and always override the text in your controls.

Comment: It's purpose is to override the text with information determined by prexisting data, as well as have it editable in text or any other control. I don't know how to get info from a database to a textbox any other way... But to the point, why would there be an extra line if it didn't exist in the database?

Comment: So write only the last record in dv. you'll get the same result. Where exactly do you see the extra line? Can you add a screenshot?